# Is map just a more powerful each?

Tags: ruby

If you want a method that collects an array without modifying it, you can use `map`, and you'll have something that works the same as `each`. For example, you could do this:

```
array.each do |x|
  x += 10
  print "#{x}"
end
```

but you could just as easily do this:

```
array.map{|x| print (x + 10).to_s}
```

and it would have the exact same result. While `each` can only do that, `map` can alter its function using the `!`, so I don't see why I would use `each` anymore. Could you explain why I should ever use `each` instead of `map` if `map` seems more versatile?

Comment: `map` is a functional programming idiom in which you "map" a function or in Ruby's case a block over an object and return a new object.

Answer (score 1):

*No.* Use `each` for side-effects; use `map` for a (side-effect free) transformation.

While they both iterate the enumerable (at some point<sup>1</sup>), [`map` collects the transformed results](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_%28higher-order_function%29) which *should* be used. To say `map` is a more powerful `each` is like saying a method that returns an unused value is more powerful than a method does not return a value - it's not of being more powerful, it's about using the correct tool.

Thus, while `map` can "do" what `each` does (by evaluation of supplied block), it *does more* and is useful for a different task: when the transformation, and not the side-effect, is desired. It is often considered poor practice to perform side-effects in a `map` (excluding, perhaps, the mutation of the mapped objects).

<sup>1</sup>Furthermore, *`map` and `each` are not strictly interchangeable*. In lazy vs. eager situations, a transformation like [`map` can be lazy while `each` is *only* useful for side-effects and is never lazy](http://railsware.com/blog/2012/03/13/ruby-2-0-enumerablelazy/). (It is not possible for `each` to be lazy because there is no resulting sequence to "observe" and force the evaluation later.)